# Cannot find packages containing StandardController

Tags: sxa, mvc, sitecore-api

I am very new to Sitecore, trying to implement a basic controller inheriting from `StandardController`. I've followed the official Sitecore docs for setting up the environment to work with MVC here: [Sitecore for development](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/developing/developing_with_sitecore/set_up_sitecore_and_visual_studio_for_development). It's written that the nuget packages to be installed are:
Sitecore.Kernel, Sitecore.Mvc, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics

I've installed them in the same order, targeting the same package version as my Sitecore installed instance: 8.2.170728, based on the nuget repository indicated here: https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json

Even after I complete the setup indicated in the doc, I don't find any namespace containing the `StandardController` class. The namespace should be starting with something like: Sitecore.SX...

P.S: installed .NET framework is v4.6.1, using VisualStudio 2017

Below is what I have installed effectively after installing Version 8.2.170728 of these nuget packages: Sitecore.Kernel, Sitecore.Mvc, Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics

[image]

Comment: Namespace: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Controllers.StandardController. Assembly: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.

Comment: I can't seem to find neither the assembly nor the namespace. I can't figure what I'm missing out. I'll add a screenshot of what I have after installing the nuget packages I've mentioned

Answer (score 4):

The XA dlls are not yet available from nuget (but they will be). At this point you can create a source-controlled /lib folder in your solution and reference the needed .XA dlls from there.

Answer (score 3):

This issue only happens (at least on "my machine") when using PackageReference instead of Packages.config.

A way to fix this is to edit the .csproj and change:

```
<PackageReference Include="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc">
  <Version>4.8.0</Version>
  <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
  <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>      
</PackageReference>
```

to

```
<PackageReference Include="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc">
  <Version>4.8.0</Version>
  <PrivateAssets>none</PrivateAssets>      
</PackageReference>
```

I got into this solution after read this: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/7686

Comment: This worked for me with PackageReferences and SXA 1.8.1 as well.

Answer (score 1):

**StandardController** comes from the **Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc** assembly, which is part of the SXA package.

Are you trying to work with SXA? If so, first you have to install the SXA package in your Sitecore instance - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator/16/Sitecore_Experience_Accelerator_16_Initial_Release.aspx - and then reference the right assemblies in your project. I believe you are following this [tutorial](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/walkthrough_building_a_new_rendering).

Now, if you are simply trying to create a controller you can use the **SitecoreController** as base. This class comes from the Sitecore.Mvc assembly.

Comment: thanks for answering. Yes I use SXA, I have already installed it using Sitecore's Backoffice through the control panel, and it's working fine. Yes again, I try to create a simple controller and cannot find the namespace you mentioned: Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc. I've installed the nuget package Sitecore.Mvc

Comment: Another precision might be helpful, my visual studio solution lives outside the installed Sitecore instance

Answer (score 1):

I finally added the reference to the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc DLL which lives in my installed sitecore instance bin/ directory.

I don't believe this is the right way to do it. So I'm leaving it open.

Comment: This is really the right way. Close this question ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's now available in the Sitecore nuget feed v3:

https://sitecore.myget.org/F/sc-packages/api/v3/index.json

From there, you can install the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc package in your project and reference the Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Mvc.Controllers in your code.